# Connected React component unnecessarily re-renders when parent re-renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React component that is connected to the redux store via implementation of mapStateToProps. React-redux connect implements a shallow-equality shouldComponentUpdate that should prevent re-renders if props do not change (based on references). However, unless I make my component explicitly pure (using PureComponent), my component re-renders when its parent re-renders. This should not be needed as connect should have implemented shouldComponentUpdate like PureComponent does. Any reason as to why this might be happening? Specifically, how does the implementation of connect differ from PureComponent? Doesn't connect make its wrapped component pure?

Comment: Please - provide your code. Codesandbox might be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

> connect should have implemented shouldComponentUpdate like PureComponent does

The `connect` function doesn't do that.
  `PureComponent` provides you with `shouldComponentUpdate` function which is a placeholder where you can put your performance-tweaking code.

`coonect` takes a different approach and provides 4 functions/placeholders **instead**. You can use all four or some or none to fine-tune performance. The functions are called:
 
`areStatesEqual`
`areStatePropsEqual`
`areOwnPropsEqual`
`areMergedPropsEqual`

> Doesn't connect make its wrapped component pure?

It leaves it up to you by giving you the option to use the above functions. You can mimic the shallow equality checks done by `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: The functions you mentioned that connect implements are essentially the same as making a component pure - PureComponent implements a shallow equality test of props in shouldComponentUpdate like the functions you listed ( areStatesEqual, areStatePropsEqual, areOwnPropsEqual, areMergedPropsEqual)

Comment: Moreover - I believe connect implements the above functions by default.

Comment: Yes, there is default implementation that you can override. For example `areStatesEqual` checks if the entire state changed using strict equality operators which differs from `shouldComponentUpdate` which uses shallow equality checks.

Comment: Are areStatesEqual's arguments the components state?

Comment: `areStatesEqual` gets old and new (incoming) Redux state tree and decides if the state tree change is substantial enough to call `mapStateToProps`